# Building kernel with LLVM LTO is failing

Tags: clang, kernel, llvm, clang++

I've built LLVM with LTO enabled and while trying to build kernel with it, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: LLVM gold plugin has failed to create LTO module: Opaque pointers are only supported in -opaque-pointers mode (Producer: 'LLVM15.0.0git' Reader: 'LLVM 14.0.0')
```

Any suggestions/thoughts on how to proceed with this?

Comment: The error message suggests rerunning with -opaque-pointers. Is there a particular reason not to do as it suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Check for mismatched versions of bin/lld and libLTO.dylib